# Java adding a number to array element

Tags: java

So I got 2 methods. One which will create a multi level array and pass that and a number to my other method. My other method will then add the number to each element in the array and then my first method will print the modified array. This is my code:

Method 1:

```
enter code her public void exercise18d1() {
    double[][] array1 = {{2.3,6.1},{3.3,8.6},{5.4,5.2}};
    double[][] array2 = {{2.3,6.1,7.0,3.5},{3.3,8.6},{5.4,5.5,5.2}};
    increase(array1, 1.2); //plus 1 plus 2
    increase(array2, -1);//minus 1
    print(array1,5,1);
    System.out.println();
    print(array2,5,1);
}
```

Method 2 which modifies the array.

```
  public void increase(double[][] arr, double nbr) {
    for(int i = 0;i <arr.length;i++){
        arr[i][i] += nbr;

    }
```

The problem is with the second method. I don't have any clue on how to fix this. arr[i][i]+=nbr  should mean that the element on i position should be added with nbr.
So to clarify the result should be:

```
   3,5  7,3 
   4,5  9,8 
   6,6  6,4

   1,3  5,1  6,0  2,5
   2,3  7,6
   4,4  4,5  4,2
```

Comment: The `ith` element of `arr` is an entire array. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size, you should use a List<T> or something similar for this task.

Comment: All the elements in the array should be added with nbr. The correct results should be: 3,5 7,3 4,5 9,8 6,6 6,4 1,3 5,1 6,0 2,5 2,3 7,6 4,4 4,5 4,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My other method will then add the number to each element in the array

That's not what it's doing at the moment. It's modifying each "diagonal" element. Imagine that you have a 5 x 10 array... you're currently only modifying 5 entries. You want nested loops - something like:

```
public void increaseAll(double[][] array, double amount) {
    for (double[] subArray : array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
            subArray[i] += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Or just using `for` loops:

```
public void increaseAll(double[][] array, double amount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {             
        for (int j = 0; i < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I was way off then, but I understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void increase(double[][] arr, double nbr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
       arr[i][j] += nbr;
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you can access `elements` of `multi dimensional array`.

Comment: I think you should replace `j < 2` with `arr[i].length`

Comment: @AntiHeadshot: Done. Thanks :)

Comment: So you could say that i is the row and j is the element on that row?

Comment: @Baxtex: i is a row number, j is column number, arr[i][j] is the element on ith row and jth column.